# Prove or disprove: If $f(x): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is bounded above, then $f(x+10)$ is also bounded above.

Tags: functions, proof-writing

We want to prove or disprove: If $f(x): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is bounded above, then $f(x+10)$ is also bounded above.

---

1) I need to first identify if this statement is true or not true.

2) I then need to find a method of proving this statement.

---

Looking at this, I believe the statement is true, because if a function is bounded above, and we are simply horizontally shifting the function (to the left 10 specifically in this case), then it does not change the bounded above status.

I am having trouble approaching the proof for this.

Any hints/suggestions/help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Use the definition. There is $M$ such that $f(x)<M$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$. What can you say about $f(x+10)$?

Comment: Ommit absolute value sign, question asks for bounded above.

Comment: There is a $N$ such that $|f(x+10)|<N$ for all $(x+10)\in \mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: @klorzan So, can you say that $N=M$ in your comment? (Note that it doesn't really matter what $N$ is, so long as you have an explanation that it exists.)

Comment: I'm thinking that I can. I'm thinking about the function $sin(x)$, which is bounded from above for $M=1$, and thinking that $sin(x+10)$ is also bounded above from $N=1$. Is there a way that I can prove this generally using this?

Comment: @z100 Corrected, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the definition and observe that $x \mapsto x+10$ defines a bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.